# D3 circular table for qualitative data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create something that looks like this:

[image]

I have gotten partially there with this code:

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

    var pie = d3.pie()
        .startAngle(-Math.PI)
        .endAngle(Math.PI);

    var outerRadius = (125);
    var innerRadius = 100;

    var categories = 12;
    var cData = d3.range(categories).map(()=>1);
    var externalData = [0,0,2,0,1,2,3,1,3,2,4,5,3,2,1];

    var data = pie(cData);

    data.forEach(function(item,i) {
      item.tier = externalData[i];
    });

    var pieG = graphGroup.selectAll(null)
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('g');

    //console.log(data)

    var colorMap = {
      0:'#003366',
      1:'#95b3d7',
      2:'#d9d9d9',
      3:'#f6d18b',
      4:'#e4a733',
      5:'#a6a6a6'
    };

    var offset = 250;

    for (var k = 0; k < 8; k++) {

      pieG.append('path')
        .attr('transform', "translate("+offset+","+offset+")")
        .attr("d", d3.arc().innerRadius(50+(25*k)).outerRadius(50+(25*(k+1))))
        .style('stroke', '#fff')
        .style('stroke-width', "2px")
        .style('fill', function(d) { return colorMap[d.tier]});

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

I have created 8 layers of donuts quite efficiently with my for loop, but I then realized that I may have lost the ability to assign each segment its own datum. As it stands, each "column" is all one color.

### Question

Is there a way for me to regain granular control of the individual segments in my muli-tier donut chart given my for-loop above? (suppose I wanted different colors in one "column" or wanted some to be empty, ect). If not, is there a comparably efficient alternative?

Comment: If you ever feel the need to use a for-loop with D3, that's clear indication that you are off track. You almonst certainly use the power of data binding with its implicit loops. That aside, you might be better off employing some sort of a [radial stacked bar chart](https://www.google.com/search?q=d3js+radial+stacked+bar+chart), e.g.:  https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3686329aa6e1f5938df8eef12ec353fe, https://observablehq.com/@d3/radial-stacked-bar-chart, https://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/9f3932d3c7154f8ab3ea2078b2aca113

Comment: I like the look of this chart - I'd be interested in seeing your code when you have worked out how to do it (as long as you can share :))

Answer (score 0):

Think in term of variables:

- `tier`,`k` are radial to the circle, the more `k` the more far from center
- `d`,`i` , the datum and the index, move along the circle

I guess you want something like this.

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

    var pie = d3.pie()
        .startAngle(-Math.PI)
        .endAngle(Math.PI);

    var outerRadius = (125);
    var innerRadius = 100;

    var categories = 12;
    var cData = d3.range(categories).map(()=>1);
    var externalData = [0,0,2,0,1,2,3,1,3,2,4,5,3,2,1];

    var data = pie(cData);

    data.forEach(function(item,i) {
      item.tier = externalData[i];
    });

    var pieG = graphGroup.selectAll(null)
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('g');

    //console.log(data)

    var colorMap = {
      0:'#003366',
      1:'#95b3d7',
      2:'#d9d9d9',
      3:'#f6d18b',
      4:'#e4a733',
      5:'#a6a6a6'
    };
    
    var emptyColor = '#FDFBFF';
    var offset = 250;

    for (var k = 0; k < 8; k++) {

      pieG.append('path')
        .attr('transform', "translate("+offset+","+offset+")")
        .attr("d", d3.arc().innerRadius(50+(25*k)).outerRadius(50+(25*(k+1))))
        .style('stroke', '#fff')
        .style('stroke-width', "2px")
        .style('fill', function(d,i) {           
           if (k < d.tier) 
              return colorMap[k];
           else
              return emptyColor;
              });

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

**Explanation of my code:**

```
   // check if this particular value is greater than the current tier
   if (d.tier > k) 
      // assign this tier color
      return colorMap[k];
   else
      // assign and empty color (light gray) if the value is not enough
      // to "reach" this tier
      return emptyColor;
      });
```

You can substitute the loops for functions to achieve this in a d3 style but you will have to rethink all the code.